# Will groups with more number of users cause the page to load slower?

Tags: organic-groups, performance

Anonymous page takes 1 to 2 secs to load
After the successful login, we are showing the same page but with some menu. I have disabled that menus too. But the page load takes 10 secs to load with same content.
We have groups. To check,have disabled the groups assigned to the user, then the page loads faster 1 to 2 sec. At first we though that, assigning groups might cause the issue. But the scenario is like, if I add single group which have more content(700) and  users like (1500) cause the issue.Except dat grp,if I add more  groups to the user,the page loads faster.

After disabling organic subgroups, and adding that single group causes the page to load faster.

Can you share your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The more modules you add to a site, the more code that likely has to execute, which equates to more overhead per request. Organic Groups particularly can be heavy, depending on what you are trying to achieve. I do not know how much progress they've made in the last few years, but in my experience it was always pretty heavy.

Logged in users also bypass caching, whereas anonymous users see as much cache as possible. This isn't as true for 8.x, but the differences in 7.x can be pretty black and white. Juggling multiple logged in users simultaneously can put a hurt on low end setups or especially if you haven't implemented caching. Or a runaway module could be calling functions every single request per user, adding to that time.

Honestly, the best tools that will help you pin down potential bottlenecks are xhprof and using a service like New Relic. It will give you far more intel about your application than anyone here ever could.

Other things you can do simply comes down to good planning. Are pages made up of lots of Views? Implement Views caching on displays that don't change often. Are you using Panels? Do you need to use Panels? Are you running memcache, does PHP have 256M memory limit, is your server underpowered?

I would start with [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/), honestly, and xhprof. New Relic is easier to setup than xhprof, depending on your experience. You will need to profile your site before you know what steps to take first.

If you are running Drupal 8, also install the [Web Profiler toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) included with Devel.